# Add customizer class to remove the space between bars in Bar chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to add the customizer class to remove the space between bars in Bar chart but I am getting some errors in iReport after adding **customizer class** property  to **package barchartcustomizer** . I have also added barchartcustomizer.jar in class path of iReport.

My Code:-

```
package barchartcustomizer;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractChartCustomizer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;


public class BarChartCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

CategoryPlot categoryPlot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();

//Spaces between bars
renderer.setItemMargin(0.03);       
}
}
```

But when I click on the preview getting this error :-

Error filling print... Could not create chart customizer instance. 
Setting up the file resolver...  Added file resolver...  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not create chart customizer instance.      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.(JRFillChart.java:299)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.visitChart(JRFillObjectFactory.java:702)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseChart.visit(JRBaseChart.java:639)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:89)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.(JRFillElementGroup.java:83)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.(JRFillElementContainer.java:90)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.(JRFillBand.java:92)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getBand(JRFillObjectFactory.java:505)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSection.(JRFillSection.java:74)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getSection(JRFillObjectFactory.java:481)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillGroup.(JRFillGroup.java:81)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getGroup(JRFillObjectFactory.java:457)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillVariable.(JRFillVariable.java:84)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getVariable(JRFillObjectFactory.java:437)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.addVariable(JRFillDataset.java:335)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setVariables(JRFillDataset.java:325)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.(JRFillDataset.java:279)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getDataset(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1338)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:397)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package com.xyz.bar.chart.customizer      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)      at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:252)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.(JRFillChart.java:296)      ... 29 more

How can I solve this error any suggestion would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you add class to classpath?

Comment: yes I have added in classpath of iReport.

Comment: What version of *iReport* are you using? Can you post all steps to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Sharad  Show part of jrxml with definition customiser class: 
<xyBarChart><chart customizerClass="whatWroteHere?"

Comment: @sanBez As I have updated my question also to call customizer class in iReport jrxml I am writing "package barchartcustomizer".

Comment: Not package. It must be class. Write like this com.xyz.bar.chart.barchartcustomizer.BarChartCustomizer (after update question error in stacktrace don't corresponds customizer package?)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following url:

https://mdahlman.wordpress.com/tag/pie-chart/

You can download readily available customizer jar under 'Sample reports and the Chart Customizer' section of the above link.

Download the jar,  register the jar in ireport classpath and add package name in the chart customizer property of ireport.

I've tested and is working fine.

Cheers,

Srikanth Kattam

Comment: I tried to download but could not and chartcustomizer2 is for Pie labels not for Bar. I you have link can you just copy those download link.